# Replacing 1 character with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to process a change of a specific character with regex using sed.

Essentially I am running a bash script that is renaming files that have a specific string and I need to keep this string mostly constant. Here is an example file name:

```
_FILE20210714.023.jpg
```

So I am trying to create a variable `nfile` that is used for the `mv` command and will convert it to the following:

```
_FILE20210714.123.jpg
```

Keep in mind that I only want to change the last 0 to a 1.

I came up with the following regex to grab that specific character, but I'm lost on how to substitute with `sed`:

```
_FILE\d{8}\.\K0

nfile=$(echo ${file}| sed -e 's/_FILE\d{8}\.\K0/_FILE\d{8}\.\K1/')
```

when i then echo the `nfile` variable i get the original name and i'm not sure how to resolve this.

```
echo ${file}
echo ${nfile}
/home/user/_FILE20210714.023.jpg
/home/user/_FILE20210714.023.jpg
```

So essential once I can substitute the `023` to `123` I'm set only problem is I have multiple files that end in like `.034.jpg` so I can't direct string match it.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` doesn't support the `\d` escape sequence, you need to use `[0-9]`.

Unless you use the `-E` option, you have to escape `{}` quantifiers.

`sed` doesn't support `\K`, but I don't think it's needed here.

You need to use a capture group to copy the digits from the original name to the replacement.

```
nfile=$(echo "${file}"| sed -E -e 's/(_FILE[0-9]{8}\.)0/\11/')
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch that did work. So which part is copying the capture group in this case?is it the additional 1 that is escaped?

Comment: Yes, `\1` means to copy capture group 1.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case a simple parameter substitution should suffice:

```
for file in '_FILE20210714.023.jpg' '/home/user/_ACH20210714.023.jpg'
do
    nfile="${file//.0/.1}"
    echo "######################"
    echo " file: ${file}"
    echo "nfile: ${nfile}"
done
```

This generates:

```
######################
 file: _FILE20210714.023.jpg
nfile: _FILE20210714.123.jpg
######################
 file: /home/user/_ACH20210714.023.jpg
nfile: /home/user/_ACH20210714.123.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have [the perl `rename`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/prename.1p.html) on your system, you'd write

```sh
rename -v 's/\.0(\d+\.jpg)$/.1$1/' *.jpg
```

---

Since you tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

```sh
newname () {
    local parts=() IFS="."
    read -ra parts <<< "$1"
    parts[1]="1${parts[1]#0}"
    echo "${parts[*]}"
}

for file in *.jpg; do
    mv -v "$file" "$(newname "$file")"
done
```

Comment: Glenn I greatly appreciate your function that you added. I'm trying to breakdown the command to understand how it functions. I see that you placed things into an array after cleaning up the entries but I am confused on how this works in totality. If you could provide a breakdown i'd greatly appreciate it.